# Finding exact value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve problem how to find exact value from string.

[image: Database]

The problem is then searching in Column `StringB` for the value `1`, it finds all rows containing `1`. The idea is that if I look for value `1` in `StringB` it should only find where value is exact.

Using `LIKE` is not a perfect option since it will take all rows which contains `1`, using `=` also is not a option since it searches for equal value.
Also tried to use `INSTR`, but it works almost same as `LIKE`.
Same with `Locate`.

There is currently stored formats:

- number (example: "2" without "")
- number. (example: "2." without "")
- number.number (example: "2.23.52.12.35" without "")

And they don't change.

This column only stores numbers, no letter or other type of string ONLY numbers (integer type)

Is there any way to strictly search for value?

My database is InnoDB.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: you describe all the stored "formats", which are actually just all strings, but then say the column is an "int" type column. These two statements contradict each other. Please can you clarify?

Comment: regex can help you something on lines ^2[\\.]??

Comment: I mean that there is no float or double type like 2.5, 2.5 mean 2 and 5 and if i look for number 5 it should count as found, or if i looking for 2 its also counts.

Comment: What is `2.23.52.12.35`?  It's not a number, to be certain.  Your question implies that you are storing numbers as text.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, its php array used with implode.

Comment: Have you tried something like `LIKE '1%'`

Comment: It would perfect solution for me but number I search could be in the middle string, begin or end of string AND it searches for simmilar values NOT exact.

Comment: "Yes, its php array used with implode" ...I see. If your database was correctly normalised you would really not be storing multiple values in the same field, and would not have this kind of problem. This probably calls for a child table with a foreign key. Then a query to find the right value would be trivial.

Comment: Logical question why make two request instead of 1? :D

Comment: @JonZ are you talking to me? If so please tag me with an @ , I only saw this by chance. Who said anything about two requests? If you had the two tables I described, you'd link them together in a single Select query via a Join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT('.', StringB, '.') REGEXP CONCAT('[.]', '2', '[.]');
```

### Demo

We could also use `LIKE` instead of `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONCAT('.', StringB, '.') LIKE CONCAT('%.', '2', '.%');
```

Comment: No numbers are integer type, which mean if I have 1.10.11.12.13 and looking for 12 it has to count as found, but if i looking for 2 this row is not found. it does not matter if it has 12 i looking for exact 2.

Comment: Working like pro @TimBiegeleisen thank you very much

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid Maybe we could use `LIKE` here, but regex is what popped into my mind first.

Comment: Good question, I don't know the answer; you may try both.  I _might_ expect `LIKE` to outperform `REGEXP` as invoking a regex engine always has an overhead.  Try both and go with the best option.

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
where stringB = 1
```

Then MySQL has to figure out what types to use.  By the rules of SQL, it will convert `'1.00'` to a number -- and they match.

If you do

```
where stringB = '1'
```

Then the types do what you intend.  And the values are compared as strings.

More:  Keep the types consistent.  Don't ever depend on implicit conversion.

Comment: but what if I have 1.10.12.13 and I looking for 2 it will it counts as found or not?

Comment: `2` would never match `'1.10.12.13'`, regardless of type.

Comment: Using = it counts as not found if using LIKE it will find.

Comment: @GordonLinoff He is trying to match exact integers inside a dot-separated string.